# Database/Models structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, crud

I am new in web development and trying to learn on my small project but got stuck with the database/model structure. Web application is for buying/selling new/second hand products(Cars, Real estate, technology, etc..). All listings or ads would have a couple of same attributes like Title, Description, Price, Location, DateCreated, but Real estate and Cars would have additional fieles related only to them like for car( Mileage, Make, Model) for real estate (NumberOfRooms, EnergyRating...). Then in page /upload-ad, I was thinking to have a button list where you can choose the category of the listing/ad, and those buttons will redirect users to certain submit forms that are related to the listing that is gonna be created. Only Cars and Real Estate have additional fields/attributes, and all other listings will have the same information except category that will be chosen in the dropdown list in the form. I think that structure of my models is completely wrong, any advice on how to achieve this?

Currently, I have 3 tables and can create cars, properties and listings, but can't figure out how to make a category selector at the index page /upload-ad that redirect the user to submit the form for that category

Now I have class BaseModel

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string OwnerID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime ListingCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Generic model class for all other listings/ad that are not Cars/Real Estate

```
 public class Listing : BaseModel
{
    
    public int ListingID { get; set; }
   
}
```

Car

```
    public class Car : BaseModel
{
   
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [Display (Name="Year of manufacture")]
    public int YearOfManufacture { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
   
   

}
```

Property/Real Estate

```
   public class Property: BaseModel
{
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Energy Rating")]
    public string EnergyRating { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext

```
public PropertyMarketplaceContext (DbContextOptions<PropertyMarketplaceContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Property> Property { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Listing> Listing { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can cast the Listings to the other classes ((Car)myListing).ListingID

Comment: Would you mind to explain how to cast listing to other classes. That means when cars are created listing id is gonna be assigned to car that has been created? Thank you